# Wordpress. Count posts in query with meta

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

How can I count posts in such a query:

```
$countPosts = ???????
$tires = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts'   => $countPosts,
    'post_type'     => 'tires',
    'meta_query'    => array(
       'relation'       => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'       => 'tire_width',
            'value'     => '175',
            'compare'   => '=',
        ),
        array(
            'key'       => 'tire_height',
            'value'     => '70',
            'compare'   => '=',
        ),

    ),
));
```

I need total number of posts for pagination

Comment: The answer to your question can be found here (using WP_Query):
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/99089/count-posts-returned-by-get-posts-in-external-php-script

Comment: use php `count()`. For your example `$countPosts = count($tires);`

Comment: Not best solution. I can have 50 000 posts. As far as I understand there is no way to do it with WP tools.